# highlighting text in <insert type="text"> is resetting (hiding) submenu & jquery vs transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

<del>1. As in title,highlighting text in  is resetting (hiding) submenu(since it's based on javascript i have used few event prevents written below @3 but none helped to stop turning whole submenu off)</del>
  2. Does CSS3 transit goes over jQuery or jQuery over CSS3? And how to make CSS3 transit "click" event and then make it return false after second click on the item? (if it's possible, the idea is to keep "opacity/fade" animation as long as the submenu is open).

<del>3. How to prevent my navbar to stop going top after clicking on "special item" (via javascript). I have tried 3 variations in each function: e.preventDefault / event.stopPropagation() / return false() at the end, before last "});".</del>

PS. Only chrome support at the moment
-> https://jsfiddle.net/34ho1fd9/7/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".account").click(function(e)
{
    var X=$(this).attr('id');
    if(X==1)
    {
        $(".submenu").hide();
        $(this).attr('id', '0'); 
    }

    else
    {
        $(".submenu").show();
        $(this).attr('id', '1');
    }
    return false;
});

//Mouse click on sub menu
$(".submenu").mouseup(function(e)
{
    return false
});

    //Mouse click on my account link
$(".account").mouseup(function(e)
{
    return false
});

//Document Click
$(document).mouseup(function(e)
{
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".account").attr('id', '');
});
return false;

/*$(".transition").click(function())
{
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.8, function()
    {

    });

}); 
return false; */
});
```

Comment: What table? I'm not seeing what you mean in 1.

Comment: i mean the "zone" where you put your text in <input type="text"> after clicking the "special link" element

Comment: Your code is poorly designed, to start with. You should attach Events only to the pertinent Elements, and use one `$(document).ready()`, then get back to us.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much, advice small but big enough to solve majority of my 3rd mini problem!